# how to auto refresh MVC PartialView every second

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery, partial-views

i need to auto refresh a partialView in the page every second (or a set interval of time)

i thought of the following method is this rite

```
  loop 
{
     setInterval(function() {  <%Html.RenderPartial("partialview", Model);%> } ,1000 );
}
```

or is there a better way using ajax stuff ?

Comment: Can you post your partial view?

Answer (score 7):

The easiest way to do this would be to have a Controller action which returns your partial view then in the setInterval function just make an ajax get request. Something like this:

```
  $.ajax({
            url: '/MyController/PartialViewAction',
            type: "GET",
            success: function(result) {
               $("#partialContainer").html(result); 
            }
        });
```