# How can I refresh my page every second using Ajax in MVC?

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to create a mechanism in my page such that it refreshes the table data everysecond using Ajax. How can I do that?

Comment: [Refresh every second?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508765/how-to-auto-refresh-mvc-partialview-every-second) [Why?](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/SignalR)

Comment: ?? Just use setInterval and put your logic there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming that you have a controller action that will return the table as a partial view you can use:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        setInterval(loadTable,1000);  // invoke load every second
        loadTable(); // load on initial page loaded
    });

    function loadTable() {
        $('#tablecontainer').load( '/controller/tabledata' );
    }
</script>

<div id="tablecontainer">
</div>
```

You'd have your tabledata action return a partial view containing the table.

```
 <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
 </table>
```

**EDIT** to establish via a click handler (script tags omitted)

```
$(function() {
     var timer;
     $('#enableCheckbox').change( function() {
         if ($(this).find(':checked').length) {
             timer = setInterval(loadTable,1000); // set up timer
             loadTable();
         }
         else if (timer) { // stop the interval timer
             clearInterval(timer);
             timer = null;
         }
     });
 });

 function loadTable() {
     $('#tablecontainer').load( '/controller/tabledata #innercontainer' );
 }
```

Full View  (contains at least the following )

```
 <div id="tablecontainer">
 <div id="innercontainer">
 <table>
    <thead>...</thead>
    <tbody>...</tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to use the Ajax response callback and only then (inside the callback) set up a new `setTimeout(loadTable, 1000);`. That way the browser won't explode if some of the Ajax request take a little longer `:P`

Comment: Hi Thank you for the code but here the problem is that my whole view is getting refreshed every second because of function `codeloadTable() {
        $('#tablecontainer').load( '/task2/index' );
    }`, while I just want to refresh #tablecontainer div

Comment: @Cal - you can add a filter in the url using a hash `$('#tablecontainer').load('/task2/index #tablecontainer');`  Better though to refactor your actions/views to have an action that returns just the partial or perhaps have the action be aware of the source of the request (`Request.IsAjaxRequest()`) and return the partial view with the table.

Comment: @Šime - I probably wouldn't require the the client be updated every second.  Using the callback to schedule the next task would be ok if the requirement isn't rigid since it will tend to drift (i.e. it will be slightly longer than a second and will vary based on the timeliness of the response).  If you're on an intranet - which is about the only place where I can imagine that once per second would be reasonable, the request takes only a few ms, and you really want it to tick like a clock every second, then setInterval is the way to go. Using a timeout smaller than 1s would be good though.

Comment: Hi That code worked. I knwo this is rather asking too much but just curious. What if I want to execute that code only if some checkbox is clicked?

Comment: @Cal then set it up so that the interval timer is created/destroyed in a change handler for the checkbox.  I'll append that to my answer.

Comment: one sec I am sorry for the confusion. Actually $('#tablecontainer').load('/task2/index #tablecontainer'); still updates the whole page. I ahd error in my page that's why I did nto realize that......

Comment: @Cal - (1) it needs to be an inner container within #tablecontainer since the selected code will be inserted into the element specified by the selector.  (2) you do have an element with that id on the page, don't you?

Comment: Yes tablecontainer is a div. and there are other elements ouside that container but sadly, instead of only updating elements inside that container, it actually updates the whole page.

Comment: @Cal - I've added an updated HTML (snippet) to show how it should be structured if you're going to deliver the full view each time.  Note the change, too, to the load method.