# How to refresh partilal view in MVC after 30 seconds

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how to auto refresh MVC PartialView every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508765/how-to-auto-refresh-mvc-partialview-every-second)

I want to refresh partial view in MVC at every 30 seconds. How can I update only that much part not entire page?

Comment: please look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508765/how-to-auto-refresh-mvc-partialview-every-second

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the setTimeout javascript timer in your page and give it the ajax function which will load the partial for you. This is the timeout function prototype:

```
<script type='text/javascrit'>
function loadPartial()
{
    //your ajax call
}

 $(document).ready(function () {
     setTimeout("loadPartial",30000);
  });
</script>
```