# Can jQuery be used to remove an HTTP response header?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, httpresponse

I am in the process of designing an MVC view that will automatically refresh a partial view using AJAX using something like the technique described in **[how to auto refresh MVC PartialView every second](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1508765/how-to-auto-refresh-mvc-partialview-every-second)**.

This should work fine as long as the client has javasript enabled but I would also lie to support automatic refresh (of the entire page) for non-javascript clients.

So I'd like to set the **refresh** header in the parent action method using a custom `AutoRefreshAttribute`:

```
public class AutoRefreshAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
    public AutoRefreshAttribute(int waitSeconds)
    {
        this.WaitSeconds = waitSeconds;
    }

    public int WaitSeconds { get; set; }

    public override void OnResultExecuted(ResultExecutedContext filterContext)
    {
        filterContext.HttpContext.Response.AppendHeader(
            "refresh", 
            this.WaitSeconds.ToString());

        base.OnResultExecuted(filterContext);
    }
}

[AutoRefresh(30)]
public ViewResult Index()
{
    return this.View();
}
```

Then I'd like to write some jQuery that executes after the Index view has loaded; this should remove the **refresh** header so the entire page won't be refreshed if the client has javascript enabled.  I can then allow a partial view to be automatically refreshed using AJAX.

**Is it possible to remove an HTTP response header using jQuery?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No it is not possible. The HTTP headers have already been read long before any javascript is processed.